# How to implement this OOP case in Haskell?

Tags: oop, haskell, types

In the project I have several different types, defined in different modules and each of them has related functions (the functions have the same name and very similar meaning, so the following make sense). Now I want to create a list, in which it will be possible to have instances of all these types (simultaneously). The only possibility I can think of is something like this:

```
data Common = A{...} | B{...} | ...
```

but it implies keeping the definition in a single place, and not in different modules (for A, B, ...). Is there a better way to do this?

**UPD**

I'm rather new to haskell and write some programs related to my studying. In this case I have different `FormalLanguage` definition methods: `FiniteAutomata`, `Grammars` and so on. Each of them has common functions (`isAccepted`, `representation`, ...), so it seemed logical to have a list where elements can be of any of these types.

Comment: If you have definitions that are so complex that they take up entire files, you should consider making them less complex instead of mirroring that architecture in Haskell. Could you show an example of what exactly you are trying to model?

Comment: I'm rather new to haskell and write some programs related to my studying. In this case I have different `FormalLanguage` definition methods: `FiniteAutomata`, `Grammars` and so on. Each of them has common methods, so it seemed logical to have a list where elements can be of any of these types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are bringing an OOP mindset to Haskell by assuming the correct solution is to store distinct types in a list.  I'll begin by examining that asssumption.

Usually we store distinct types in a homogeneous list because they support a common interface.  Why not just factor out the common interface and store THAT in the list?

Unfortunately, your question does not describe what that common interface is, so I will just introduce a few common examples as demonstrations.

The first example would be a bunch of values, `x`, `y`, and `z`, that all support the `Show` function, which has the signature:

```
(Show a) => a -> String
```

Instead of storing the type we want to show later on, we could instead just call `show` directly on the values and store the resulting strings in the list:

```
list = [show x, show y, show z] :: String
```

There's no penalty for calling `show` prematurely because Haskell is a lazy language and won't actually evaluate the `show`s until we actually need the string.

Or perhaps the type supports multiple methods, such as:

```
class Contrived m where
    f1 :: m -> String -> Int
    f2 :: m -> Double
```

We can transform classes of the above form into equivalent dictionaries that contain the result of partially applying the methods to our values:

```
data ContrivedDict = ContrivedDict {
    f1' :: String -> Int,
    f2' :: Double }
```

... and we can use this dictionary to package any value into the common interface we expect it to support:

```
buildDict :: (Contrived m) => m -> ContrivedDict
buildDict m = ContrivedDict { f1' = f1 m, f2' = f2 m }
```

We can then store this common interface itself in the list:

```
list :: [buildDict x, buildDict y, buildDict z]
```

Again, instead of storing the distinctly-typed values, we've factored out their common elements for storage in the list.

However, this trick won't always work.  The pathological example is any binary operator that expect two operands of equal type, such as the `(+)` operator from the `Num` class, which has the following type:

```
(Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

As far as I know, there is no good dictionary-based solution for partially applying a binary operation and storing it in such a way that it guarantees it is applied to a second operand of the same type.  In this scenario the existential type class is probably the only valid approach.  However, I recommend you stick to the dictionary-based approach when possible as it permits more powerful tricks and transformations than the type-class-based approach.

For more on this technique, I recommend you read Luke Palmer's article: [Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: As far as I know, there's no good OO solution to binary operations like that in actual OO languages, either. In my experience, most either have special baked-in support, rely on C-style overloaded functions, or use arcane meta-programming trickery.

Comment: And is this dictionary-based solution idiomatic in haskell? It fully suits my needs, so I'm going to use it.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for dictionary versus type class is that if you are using type-directed inference then you should use a type class, otherwise you should use a dictionary (since the purpose of type classes is to automatically select the appropriate dictionary based on the type).  In this example, though, you aren't using any type-directed inference and you are only using it to store methods for instances which you have already selected in advance.  In other words, you are only using it as a dictionary, so you might as well make it a dictionary.

Comment: @chersanya Forgot to @ you on my previous comment, but I also wanted to add that even storing dictionaries in a list is usually an indicator of code smell and that you aren't doing things in an idiomatic Haskell style.  I have never needed to use this trick in my own code.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, look at the question UPD please, how would you advice to implement such a scenario?

Comment: @chersanya The non-obvious part is why you are storing them in a list in the first place.  It's not like they will run away if you don't put them inside a container.  :)

Comment: I'd want to keep several of them (not fixed number, they are input by user), and so i use a list :)

Comment: @chersanya If the user is selecting (multiple times) which `FormalLanguage` to use, you can store the user's selection as an algebraic data type (i.e. `data Choice = FiniteAutomata | Grammar | ...`).  If the user is actually defining their own `FormalLanguage` interactively and storing each one for later then the dictionary approach is what you want.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: Thanks, the latter is my case, so I'm going to use dictionaries =)

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: I wouldn't necessarily describe it as a "code smell". Passing around records of functions (a special case of type class dictionaries, note) is just a generalization of passing around single functions. If a collection of operations is the natural way to represent something, what's wrong with that? It's only a code smell if it's used inappropriately, in the same way that using a partially applied `foldr` instead of a list would be. (Or, if you prefer, using explicit state machine stream transducers instead of a free monad on stream operations, heh heh.)

Answer (score 5):

There are few possibilities:

Possibility 1:

```
data Common = A AT | B BT | C CT
```

with AT, BT and CT described in their respective modules

Possibility 2:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class CommonClass a where
    f1 :: a -> Int

data Common = forall a . CommonClass a => Common a
```

which is almost the same as OOP superclass, but you cannot do "downcasts". You can then declare implementations for members of common classes in all the modules.

Possibility 3 suggested by @Gabriel Gonzalez:

```
data Common = Common {
     f1 :: Int
}
```

So your modules implement common interface by using closures to abstract over the 'private' part.

However, Haskell design is usually radically different from OOP design. While it's possible to implement every OOP trick in Haskell, it will be likely non-idiomatic, so as @dflemstr said more information about your problem is welcome.

Comment: [Obligatory](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)

Comment: Technically, possibility 3 would be just an `Int`, not an `a -> Int`.  No extra data type necessary.

Comment: Yeah I already figured out my mistake and fixed. I think this approach resembles javascript module pattern.

Comment: Incidentally, the "record of functions" approach essentially *is* OOP encoded in Haskell, hobbled slightly by the lack of subtyping and syntactic sugar for using OO style. It also tends to be the best (and idiomatic) design in Haskell for exactly the kinds of problems that OOP was invented to solve.